# Using embedded brokers - pros and cons

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I want to setup a network of brokers because I need to serve a number of users at the same time. I discovered that I may use either embedded brokers and start every broker in a Java Code or download full apache activemq distribution and run multiple instances.

For the moment, I don't have any specific reason to use embedded brokers. But on the other hand I don't have any reasons against using embedded brokers. Could you please give a hint what may be real disadvantages of using embedded brokers?

Thanks, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You probably want stand-alone broker(s).

Embedded brokers (in an application context) are usually used inside an application server to provide for fast response/low latency to application code in the running application server. The embedded broker would then store-and-forward the messages to another broker or interested clients. Other use cases including using embedded broker in unit tests, or within an embedded IOT-style computer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But can you please give a hint - what real advantages of standalone brokers?

Comment: A good way to think of a messaging platform is that it is the highway for your apps to talk to one another in a standard, scalable and flexible way. Having the brokers be standalone allows you to perform broker maintenance and upgrades without impacting apps.